# Программное добавление цветов в xml?

Tags: android

Можно ли в Android как то наследоваться и перегрузить такую вещь как colors атрибут.

Я хочу программно изменить colorPrimary и colorPrimaryDark. в XML не получится указать ссылку на переменную.

Цвета у меня приходят динамически. Как можно всатвить цвета в XML таким образом чтобы их переписывать.

Программно писать для каждой Viewшки цвета, это очень ужасно и долго получиться. Можно ли как то переписать сам xml colors.

Может знаете какие нибудь фишки))

Comment: Прочел, но не понял, вы хотите динамически темы менять или просто где-то вам надо цвет иной, чем в теме?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, Смотрите в colors.xml есть атрибут colorPrimary. Он меняет основной цвет приложения. Кнопки, actionBar и т.д.

Так вот. Я хочу указать цвет для colorPrimary программно. Цвет для colorPrimary  я получаю динамически.

Comment: @xTIGRx Наверное вы хотите это https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178187/5805982

Comment: @xTIGRx, похоже что никак. Эти цвета используются в темах, а темы можно только переключать, ни создавать динамически, ни менять в рантайме их нельзя. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815769/how-to-really-programmatically-change-primary-and-accent-color-in-android-loll

Comment: Ладно тогда программно буду делать